# Getting an image popup overlay to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, overlay

First, code:

**CSS:**

```
.popup_foreground {
    position:   fixed;
    top:    0px;
    left:    0px;
    width:    100%;
    height:    100%;
    vertical-align:  middle;
    text-align:   center;
    z-index:   1;
}
.popup_foreground_container {
    margin:    auto;
    padding:   24px;
    background-color: white;
    border:    1px solid black;
    display:   inline-block;
    display:   -moz-inline-stack;
    max-width:   100%;
    max-height:   100%;
    z-index:   2;
}
.popup_image {
    max-height:   100%;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function popupImage( img )
{
    var fg = $( "<div class='popup_foreground'></div>" );
    var container = $( "<div class='popup_foreground_container'></div>" );
    var image = $( "<img class='image_full popup_image' src='"+img+"' />" );
    fg.append( container );
    container.append( image );

    $("body").append( fg );

    fg.click( function(){
        fg.remove();
    });
}
```

Seems to work.  Just calling function `popupImage()` displays the given image as an overlay that can be turned off with a click.  In english, there's a foreground element that is fixed to the view, a 'container' with no preset size (only padding), and an image that goes inside of the container.

My problem is that an image larger than the width or height of the screen gets squeezed out of proportion in order to fit.  I really can't have that.  I don't want to have to use scrolling.  How can I get images to scale proportionally to fit in the browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the `container.append()` line to:

```
container.append( $( "<img class='image_full popup_image' src='"+img+"' width='"+ $(container).width() +"'/>" ) );
```

It should assign the `width` of the container element to the created `img`. This might be a problem, though, for smaller images so it might be worth using an `if/else` statement to check whether the scaling is required.

Using only `width` means that the image will be scaled proportionally, whereas if you set `height` (*as well as* `width`) the image is likely to be distorted.

Comment: That´s what I was going to say, with the addition that you would have to calculate first whether it´s the `width` or the `height` that is relatively largest (compared to the screen) and use either `width` or `height` in your statement.

Comment: @Hamster Yes, otherwise you won´t know whether it´s too high or too broad. Or both.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah I just figured that out.

Comment: @Hamster By the way, there are several jQuery lightbox plugins that might already do what you want.

Comment: I want something that I can have intimate control over, though.  Plus it didn't seem like it'd be hard to make, anyhow.

Comment: No, no matter what I tried I could not get the scaling to work as long as the image was inside that container.  I had to remove it and just use the image directly.